# Made CSS slide-out menu but now I can't click on links

Tags: html, css, wordpress

So I made a basic slide out menu for the mobile view of my site that sits beneath my page and when you click on the label for a hidden checkbox, the inner wrapper slides to the right revealing the menu. It works well and is really responsive on mobile. The only problem I'm having is that I am now unable to click on the links. I've tried raising the z-index and that hasn't done a lick of good.
Any help would be hot.
Here's the link to the site: [flatland.mattmcelwee.com](http://flatland.mattmcelwee.com). Shrink your browser or use Chrome's mobile emulator to look at it.

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates 
your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you div side-menu z-index, its -2 make it 0 or take it off!